Hacker Rank day 8 challenge in Golang. Why is this not working?
Go
In terminal, I get the correct output, but in hackerrank, I get one line less than what is actually suppose to output.
When I switched from using the bufio.NewReader to NewScanner, it worked and solved everything.
Can someone explain to me why?
It would be extremely helpful
Thanks.
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    // Read the number of entries
    line, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(line))

    // Create a map to store the phonebook
    phonebook := make(map[string]string)

    // Read num lines of name and phone number
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        line, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
        parts := strings.Fields(line)
        name := parts[0]
        number := parts[1]
        phonebook[name] = number
    }

    var results []string

    // Process queries until EOF
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        qu, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        qu = strings.TrimSpace(qu)
        if phone, found := phonebook[qu]; found {
            results = append(results, fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", qu, phone))
        } else {
            results = append(results, "Not found")
        }
    }

what actually works
func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    // Read the number of entries
    scanner.Scan()
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text()))

    // Create a map to store the phonebook
    phonebook := make(map[string]string)

    // Read num lines of name and phone number
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        parts := strings.Fields(scanner.Text())
        name := parts[0]
        number := parts[1]
        phonebook[name] = number
    }

    var results []string

    // Process the remaining input as queries
    for scanner.Scan() {
        qu := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())
        if phone, found := phonebook[qu]; found {
            results = append(results, fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", qu, phone))
        } else {
            results = append(results, "Not found")
        }
    }

    // Check for any scanning errors
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error reading input:", err)
    }

    // Print all results at once
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(results, "\n"))
}

fmt.Println(strings.Join(results, "\n"))

}
It is in the detail of the problem
the sample input:
3 sam 99912222 tom 11122222 harry 12299933 sam edward harry
the sample output:
sam=99912222 Not found harry=12299933
the output when using reader:
sam=99912222 Not found
output when using scanner:
sam=99912222 Not found harry=12299933

The first program does not handle the case where the file does not end with a \n.  Break out of the loop when no data is read, not on error.
for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    qu, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if len(qu) == 0 {
        break
    }

bufio.Scanner is preferred over bufio.Reader because bufio.Scanner correctly handles this end condition.
